# Mesure with complex filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to DAX, and I want to do a complex filter with it.
The thing is, I have a table :

```
TableA :

ID
PHONE (phone number of users)
TYPE_PHONE (contain either 0 or 1)
VOLUME_LTE
```

The phone number may appear more than once in the table, so I want to count the numbers of users that has `type_phone = 0`, and `SUM of VOLUME_LTE` also equal to `0`.

In SQL, I use this :

```
Select count(phone) from TableA
where type_phone = 0 and volume_lte = 0
having sum(volume_lte) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a `HAVING` clause, you'll need to calculate a table and then filter it afterward.

```
CountMeasure = 
    VAR Summary = SUMMARIZE(TableA,
                      TableA[phone],
                      TableA[type_phone],
                      "Volume", SUM(TableA[volume_lte])
                  )
    RETURN COUNTROWS(
               FILTER(Summary,
                   TableA[type_phone] = 0 && [Volume] = 0
               )
           )
```

---

Edit: You completely changed your SQL... I can't tell what you're asking anymore.

Comment: I edited the question, it does not contain a having close. Sorry.

Comment: I think I didn't explain enough, I don't want to count how many times the phone appear with those conditions, I want to count JUST the number that has 0 total volume summarized,
<br/>
phone         volume_lte<br/>
99999999    45<br/>
44455555    0<br/>

55555555    15v<br/>
44455555    0<br/>
55555555    0<br/>


So the output here is : 0 because the only number that has 0 volume in every row, is the 4445555
I hope I am clear now. And Thanks

Comment: Then your SQL is currently wrong as it gives the count of any phones of type 0 and *at least one* `volume_lte = 0`. I think you do need the `HAVING` clause to do what you want.

Comment: You were right, I had the sql wrong, I did the having that I did in the first place and it works, also your suggestion works, thank you so mcuh

Comment: I've rolled the edit back to include the `HAVING` clause so that the question makes sense.